# Why does an error occur when installing Discord PIP?

Tags: python, pip, discord.py

I decided to create a discord bot using python, but when I entered "pip install discord.py" in the command prompt, this error appeared.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

```
 command: 'c:\users\нелли\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\нелли\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\968F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmhhxtw89'

     cwd: C:\Users\Нелли\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fveo7bqy\aiohttp
Complete output (24 lines):

Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)

running dist_info

creating C:\Users\Нелли\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yh2d9tgu\aiohttp.egg-info

writing C:\Users\Нелли\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yh2d9tgu\aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO

writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Нелли\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yh2d9tgu\aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

writing requirements to C:\Users\Нелли\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yh2d9tgu\aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt

writing top-level names to C:\Users\Нелли\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yh2d9tgu\aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt

writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Нелли\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yh2d9tgu\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Нелли\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yh2d9tgu\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'

no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'

writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Нелли\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yh2d9tgu\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

creating 'C:\Users\Нелли\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yh2d9tgu\aiohttp.dist-info'

error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\нелли\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\нелли\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\968F~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmhhxtw89' Check the logs for full command output.

I have been unable to find its cause for several hours.
does anyone know what to do in a situation like this? :(

Comment: It seems to be erroring on the Unicode characters in your path. The message is telling you `Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback`. So set PYTHONVERBOSE in your shell/environment, then rerun, and post us the more detailed error message. "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)". Ignore everything below that.

Comment: The workaround would be to install in a path with only ASCII characters. But let's try to fix this first.

Answer (score 0):

I did thid, when I was install discord.py rewrite.

```
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

Hope that it will help